# How can I set the window title of a form in dialog mode?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

As the title suggest I would like to now if and how it is possible to change the text that is being displayed as the window title if I open a form as a dialog. Either via macro or vba. I don´t think there is an option in the `OpenForm` command... And i have read about the `AppTitle` property, which changes the title of my access window (not what i want).

In the following picture I would like to have a different title than `Inhalt00001`.

[image]

I am aware of the fact that the title normally depends on the name of my form. I do however want the title of the dialog to be independent of said name. Reason for that being that I want two versions of a form with different content yet the same title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can put the form into design view, then go to Property Sheet > Format > Caption and change that to whatever you want the title to be.  This is how it is done in Access 2010 anyway.

Comment: That's for a static caption. It should be set dynamically.

Comment: It `can` be set dynamically.  It depends on the nature of the form whether or not it needs be set statically or dynamically.

Comment: @Gustav you can do it dynamically, yes (unless the argument is already in use). The key for me was the `caption` property. Therefore you got an upvote, but this will be the accepted answer still. Especially since i dont really need it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to open the form specifying the OpenArgs parameter:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormName", acNormal, , , , acDialog, "Inhalt00001"
```

In the OnLoad event of the form, specify:

```
Me.Caption = Nz(Me.OpenArgs, "No Title")
```